# How does the order of cut '!' symbol affect the backtracking in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, prolog-cut, instantiation-error

how does the order we put the cut symbol '!' inside a Prolog predicate affects the results?
For example in this code:

```
p(0,Y) :- !, Y is 0.
p(X,Y) :- A is X-1, p(A,B), Y is B+X.
```

When we test with a query like p(2,3). the program answers with **true**, and even when we try this p(V,6) the program answers with **false**
But when we reverse the order of the cut symbol, like this :

```
p(0,Y) :- Y is 0, !.
p(X,Y) :- A is X-1, p(A,B), Y is B+X.
```

The program answers correctly the first query, but for the second one it returns the famous "Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated" error.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Would usually use `Y = 0` instead of `Y is 0`, so it can work when Y is var.

Comment: It's clearer now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As I answered [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73072720/478656), even though its name is an exclamation mark instead of a word and it does something outside normal logic, cut is "just another predicate" in the sense that it gets called only if execution gets to it:

```
p(0,Y) :- Y is 0, !.
```

When you query `p(V,2)` the test `Y is 0` fails, triggering backtracking, and the cut is never executed.